# Why not use bLSAG for one input instead of MLSAG?

Tags: ringct

AFAIK MLSAG is being used for one input because of a privacy problem. Why not just use bLSAG, since in the MRL005 it says that MLSAG is better once we have > 1 sets of keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLSAG allows us to include more than just the set of keys. We can thus use both keys *and* commitments.

Quoting the paper:

> An MLSAG is essentially similar to the LSAG’s described in [8], but
>   rather than having a ring signature on a set of *n* keys, instead, an
>   MLSAG is a ring signature on a set of *n* key-vectors.

Currently we use RCTTypeSimple, which creates a signature for each input ring. Each ring contains public keys and commitments. This means we are creating a signature on a matrix whereby each column represents an input that has two rows. The first row contains the key, the second the commitment. A "matrix" is another way of saying "set of *n* key-vectors".

Comment: Yes, but afaik mlsag is being used for one input at a time due to the shared index bug. In that ring, we prove that we know one of the keys that sign it. I imagine it is like a mxn matrix, where each row of keys is assigned to an input and we need to prove that we know the secret keys to an entire column.

Comment: Yes this is correct, there is one sig per input ring, but note they also link the key images - MLSAG incorporates both keys and Pedersen commitments.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The MLSAG is used to sign each input individually, how would the keyImages be linked? For n inputs, we would have n signatures each with their own keyImages afaiu

Comment: From your quote, an MLSAG signature on 1 key vector is the same as a signature of n keys, where n is the size of the key vector

Comment: If you look at how mlsag is used in Monero, you'll see that both keys and commitments are used. Not just keys or just commitments. The quote doesn't state 1 key vector, it says "on a set of n key-vectors". Also recall how you link the key image, the zero commitment.

Comment: Yes, it is originally meant to be used for n key-vectors. But because all inputs over the mlsag must share the same index,which could impact privacy if one input was revealed, mlsag is used to only sign one input at a time, right?

Comment: Because each input is signed individually, there is a pseduoOut for each input. The pseudoOuts then aggregate to ensure that the sumInputs-SumOuts-fH = 0

Comment: Yes there is one mlsag per ring. But both keys *and* commitments are added.

Comment: Oh I think we are speaking about the same thing. When you said "KeyImages are linked" I thought you meant all keyImages over all inputs

Comment: Do you agree that as a matrix, each row would be a set of n keys whereby one of them is equal to the signers key? Each row is then assigned to an input with decys. And the signer needs to prove that he owns all keys to column. This is for the MLSAG ringsig

Comment: No. There is a signature for each ring. Each sig is formed from a matrix whereby each column represents each input for that ring. For each column, there are 2 rows. The first row contains the key, the second the commitment. [src](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/581994b61c9b8b530629b2dbc2e7ddd3b30b12b4/src/ringct/rctSigs.cpp#L528).

Comment: Also would be nice to add: Signing multiple inputs would still have two rows. The commitments would be aggregated and the keys would be aggregated. I think

Comment: As I have stated, there are always 2 rows. The first row for each column has the input public key, the second has the commitment (which is also technically a key). Therefore, a ring of 6 inputs has 6 columns and 2 rows. I can't say this any clearer. bLSAG only allows for one dimension, MLSAG allows for multi-dimension.

Comment: My confusion is from the monero paper, where they say that multiple inputs cannot be signed because they will share the same index. Which is not the case if they are in different columns in the matrix.